# Alternative to column name "order" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When I create a new table that need an ordering defined by the user, my first idea always go to a column name "order". Of course, this is NOT good since it's a reserved word.

Which name are you giving to that column in your database models ?

Comment: I lean toward using `weight`. `order`, `position`, and others imply a continuous ordering of records. `weight` implies that there can be gaps (which is often a more performant implementation since it requires updating fewer records on insertion and deletion).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I often use simple synonyms, "sort" for example.

Comment: best answer, I also like `sort_order` to make it even more explicit 

Answer (score 108):

I use "position" in place of "order"

Comment: +1 `ORDER BY position` certainly reads better than `ORDER BY sort` - and "sort" could be confused with "type".

Comment: The problem with `position` is that it's considered a reserved word in some SQL flavors. see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: @Mustafa how about PositionNo in this case?

Comment: @Yiping Then I'd go for orderNo ;)

Comment: Instead of `position` one can also just use `pos`.

Answer (score 12):

Just add the tick mark ` around the names of your tables and columns, for example:

```
  CREATE TABLE `order`
  (
         `order#` char(4) NOT NULL,
         `ord_date` DATE,
         Primary Key (`order#`)
  )
  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This allows for special characters and keywords to be used, at least this works for the current version of MySql.

Comment: I know, but I'm using Ebean and for a reason I can't understand, it doesn't add those ticks, so if I name a column using a reserved keyword, it fails.

Answer (score 7):

In ANSI/ISO SQL, double quotes delimit keywords when used as column names; string literals are delimited by single quotes:

```
select "from" = 'from' from foo
```

Microsoft SQL Server allows the use of square brackets in lieu of the double quotes as well:

```
select [from] = 'from' from foo
```

But either way, it makes a dreadful mess of your code (try reading the above to someone.)

If I need an column for ordering results, I generally call it something like 'sequence_number' or 'sort_sequence'.

Comment: 'sort_sequence' I like that

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server, at least, allows you to use keywords if enclosed in square brackets, although I agree it's not a great idea.

I believe the last time I did this, I used SortOrder for the name. However, I often use prefixes that reflect the table such as UsrSortOrder so that's not always an issue.

Comment: The problem is that I use JPA and it goes crazy with or without brackets :/ I have to change the name. But finally it's not so bad since this word is reserved ;). Thanks for your reply

Comment: I guess JPA will be more comfortable if you use the ANSI standard for quoting names: double quotes. Those brackets are a SQL Server "speciality" but the standard quoting is understood as well (don't know if a configuration change is required for that). So `"order"` might actually work. But I would still recommend to find a different name. Having to quote object names will lead to problems eventually.